# "Segmented Button" with Multi-line Text

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm not sure exactly what keyword I should be searching, but I wasn't able to find the answer to my problem - I'm new to iOS development so apologies in advanced if I'm not using the correct UI components.

I want to create something like a *segmented control* (two choices) with multi-line descriptions in them, except I'm not sure if I should be using a *segmented control* to do so, or to customize a *button* to create it. The user should be able to select a "choice" and that will switch views and tint the choice not selected depending on the choice the user makes. How exactly would I design this / is this possible?

I've already attempted to modify the *segmented control* but couldn't get the desired results. I've thought about creating a text box and modifying it to act like a button selector, but wasn't sure if that was the best way. I would love some input, thanks!

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on what is supposed to happen when the user taps a choice. If the user taps choice 1, are you going to replace the entire view/tableview with choice 1 view?

Comment: Yes, I would obtain data from some URL and parse it depending on the choice. For example, Choice 1 would perhaps get data from www.foo.com while Choice 2 will get it from www.bar.com. 

Edit: Just to clarify, it'll go into a different view, as all these will be tied by a navigation controller.

Comment: But the action happens when the user taps a row in the table, yes? In that case, a UISegmentedControl seems like the reasonable choice. However, it does not appear to support multiline text. If you search for "multiline UISegmentedControl" you can find some solutions people have come up with, but I myself have not tried any of them.

Comment: Your idea of using some other control to simulate the UISegmentedControl appearance is also viable. You could probably use a couple of simple UILabels and wire up UITapGestureRecognizer to them.

Comment: Yes, the action happens when the user taps a row in the table and the new view is dependent on what the user chooses. I think I try rolling with your UITapGestureRecognizer advice, I nearly forgot about that tidbit while going through the Swift tutorials! Thank you! I'll wait a few more days for more suggestions, but will look into seeing whether my the UISegmentedControl will be viable.